# return a variable from ajax and php on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using `AJAX (jQuery)` to post a form to `user-ajax.php` but the page actually needs to echo out a response such as `"success"`. in ajax code im testing the response value if its equal to success im doing something but it's not working here is the php code

```
function ajaxlogin($config,$lang){
   //something
        $response = 'success';
        echo $response;

}
```

the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        $("#login-status").show();
        var action = $("#lg-form").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            action: action,
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert (response); //this alert show "success"
                if (response == 'success') {
                    $("#lg-form").slideUp('slow', function () {
                        $("#login-status").removeClass('info-notice').addClass('success-notice');
                        $("#login-status #login-status-message").html('Logged in success. Redirecting....');
                        location.reload();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#login-status").removeClass('info-notice').addClass('error-notice');
                    $("#login-status #login-status-message").html(response);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

My problem is that the alert show `"success"` but the `"if (response == 'success')"` instruction isn't executed it goes directly to else. normally `'success'== 'success'`.

Comment: Are you sure the response string does not include any other characters? Like, can you `console.log(response.length)` and make sure it's 7?

Comment: Trim it like here: if($.trim(response)=='success'){} you may have some white space there.

Comment: you should add the complete and exact code that you are using the PHP file / function `function ajaxlogin($config,$lang)`

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for your help, i did console.log(response.length) and it shows 8 i used  if($.trim(response)=='success') and it's work. thx a l ot for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx a lot for your help. I did exactly like you suggest console.log(response.length) and it shows 8. and i used if($.trim(response)=='success') and it's working. thx a lot for your support